# Setting Window background color using resource

Tags: wpf, resources, colors, background, window

I need to use a resource to set the color of the main window in my WPF application. Since the resource declaration comes after the window declaration (I am importing a resource dictionary), I can't use a `Background` property in the `Window` object. So, I thought I would set the background this way:

```
<Window.Resources>
...
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"  />
</Window.Background>
```

My syntax is a bit off, since the  object won't take a brush resource for its Color property. What's the fix? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window.Background>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="WindowBackgroundBrush" />
</Window.Background>
```

Answer (score 19):

this works:

```
<Window x:Class="Moria.Net.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        x:Name="window"
        Background="{DynamicResource WindowBrush}"
        Width="800" Height="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBrush" Color="LightGray"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

the main thing to note here is the x:name in the window, and the DynamicResource in the Background property

alternativly, this works as well....

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBrush" Color="LightGray"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
```

As a side note, if you want to use theming for you application, you should look into [component resource keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753186.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put your resources in App.xaml instead.  That way you can set the Background on your Window without any problems.

Comment: A solution, but not the solution. And it is a bad fit for applications that involve multiple projects, such as Prism apps.